# how use np.argwhere to get the non zero and zero values?

Tags: arrays, position, pixel

l am using this line of code to get the positions for the red pixel values only:

```
red_pixel_positions1 = np.argwhere(np.all(((substractions>= [0, 50, 50]) & (substractions<= [180, 255, 255])), axis=-1))
```

subtractions is an array will all the pixels values :

```
   [[249,   2,   2],
    [253,   9,   9],
    [253,  11,  11],
    ...,
    [176, 206, 221],
    [178, 207, 222],
    [164, 191, 208]],

   [[249,   2,   0],
    [246,   1,   2],
    [251,   8,   8],
    ...,
    [171, 202, 216],
    [166, 196, 210],
    [141, 169, 187]],

   ...,
```

So my wish is to get the all the positions regarding the conditions but do not remove all the values that didn't meet the condition just give them a position value 0. l am doing that because at the and l would like to analyze 2 arrays with the same shape. How can l do that with argwhere ?